# Query plain BSON using Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Is it possible to query Spring Data MongoDB for the plain JSON / BSON data without having the data converted to the actual model implementation?

All I could find is the MongoOperation's `<T> T findOne(Query query, Class<T> entityClass);` and the MongoTemplate's `<T> T findOne(Query query, Class<T> entityClass);` method. Both of them return the converted model, not plain data. Is it as simple as passing in `DBObject` or `BSONObject` as class parameter?

Comment: I wonder if the best approach would be to pass the JSON to the underlying Mongo Java driver. I'm guessing there's a method somewhere in the API that would give you a reference to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is, but I guess you could've just tried it in the same time you wrote down that question?

```
Query query = new BasicQuery("{\"emailAddress\" : \"user@acme.com\"}");
DBObject result = template.findOne(query, DBObject.class);
```

Comment: Is it really that simple? How is the collection name derived? I had no luck with that approach (empty result). Finally `Document result = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, Document.class, <collectionName>);` worked for me. But I guess I just missed something, because Oliver definitely knows what he's talking about.