# With spring-data-mongodb repositories, how can I retrieve all properties in a Map<String, Object> without having to name the properties individually?

Tags: mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I am using `spring-data-mongodb` with Repository interfaces to query some collections.  I had to disable `MongoAutoConfiguration` because I needed to be able to query two separate collections from two separate databases within MongoDB.  So, in my `@Configuration` class, I manually created two separate `MongoTemplate` beans to facilitate this, and it works great.

For one of the repositories, I have a method that uses a `@Query` annotation with a JSON query string.  I want to have a model class that captures the `@Id` in one variable, and *all other properties* in a `Map<String, Object>` like I have seen in several examples:

```
@Document(collection = "#{@collectionName}")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DynamicModel {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private Map<String, Object> properties;
}
```

But this is not working for me, and I am curious if it has something to do with a converter that I have inadvertently left out when creating my custom mongo templates and disabling the mongo autoconfiguration.  Note that I have also tried including `@JsonAnySetter` and `@JsonAnyGetter`, but the result was the same, with nothing stored within the properties map.

As a work-around, I can switch to using a `@Aggregation` method in the repository, and use a projection stage that puts everything into a named sub-document map.  If I name that map "properties", like in the code example above, then it works as expected.

Note: Bonus points if I could use a map that is already existing in the document and have spring-data-mongodb put all unspecified fields into it!

Update:  I have had success with a `@PersistenceConstructor` and with adding a custom converter implementation.  I am starting to assume that these two approaches are the only ways that I can achieve what I am looking for, although I was hoping for some default behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one mentioned a better way, I will post my workaround as an answer.  I used a `@ReadingConverter` to consolidate all of the properties into a map in the document.  The documents already had a map that contained all of the fields specific to each document subtype, and each document contained a list of standard fields outside of the map.  I added this reading converter to the mongo template's custom conversions.  Now I can process the map and get all of the fields.  I just wish there was a more generic way to do it, but I imagine that would be pretty difficult if the code has no knowledge of the document structure.

Comment: I suggest taking a look also at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34897186/565110